# Redirection of url

Tags: redirects, godaddy

Is it possible to when a user type

```
xxxx.com
```

that the url 
change for

```
www.xxxx.com
```

or better that all request go to

https://www.xxxx.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and it is a well known process often called as setting up your preferred (canonical) destination.

You should use 301 redirects to send traffic from the *non-www* URLs to the *www* URLs. It is a good practice also if use Search Console to set your [preferred domain](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231).

> To implement a 301 redirect for websites that are hosted on servers
>   running Apache, you'll need access to your server's .htaccess file.
>   (If you're not sure about your access or your server software, check
>   with your webhoster.) For more information, consult the Apache
>   .htaccess Tutorial and the Apache URL Rewriting Guide. If your site is
>   hosted on a server running other software, check with your hoster for
>   more details.

Read more [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en)

Comment: it's tomcat embedded who are used (via spring boot)

Comment: @bernardderomme have a look at http://nematodes.org/martin/2010/02/04/301-permanent-redirect-with-tomcat-howto/